# how to calculate sum of @property function in django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I want to calculate the sum of `total_amount` property. Here is my models.py

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    order_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    order_item = models.ForeignKey('Product', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='order_item', blank=True, null=True,
        related_name='ordered_item')
    order_status = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    delivery_address = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey('User', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='customer', blank=True, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    date_time = models.DateTimeField()
  
    
    @property
    def total_amount(self):
        rate = Product.objects.get(pk=self.order_item.product_id)
        total_amount = rate.price * self.quantity
        return total_amount

    @property
    def unit_rate(self):
        rate = Product.objects.get(pk=self.order_item.product_id)
        return rate.price
```

Comment: It seems you have a function to do that. What is your question exactly?

Comment: for example, i want monthly revenue, then i need sum of `total_amount` column in a month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a property method for that. Instead use [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/) like this:

```
from django.db.models import Sum, F, ExpressionWrapper, DecimalField

Orders.objects.filter(date_time__month=6).annotate(
    total_amount = ExpressionWrapper(
        F('order_item__price')*F('quantity'),
        output_field=DecimalField()
    )
).aggregate(monthly_total=Sum('total_amount'))['monthly_total']
```

Comment: `Exception Value:QuerySet.aggregate() received non-expression(s): <django.db.models.fields.DecimalField>`.

Comment: If you dont mind, could you please tell me how to show it in django admin in different table ?

Comment: as per the requirement ?

Comment: Sorry, what requirement? FYI, you could add this code in a property method and use that in admin site.

Comment: I mean if admin wants the revenue of some month, then he could just get it by entering month or day ?

Comment: I think it is not in the scope of this question. Can you please ask a new one with more detail about what you want to achieve? Thanks